# Entity Framework Model or Database first and Code first without Visual Studio?

Tags: powershell, entity-framework-6

The MSDN tutorials and videos show how to use visual studio to interrogate a database and write C# code. They also show how to parse the code and generate a database. This works but it is difficult to automate.

They all use visual studio which requires mouse clicks.

(1) How can I fire up a powershell command prompt and automate the generation of C# code from a database (without using Visual Studio)?

(2) How can I automate the generation of a database from my C# code (again, using powershell and no visual studio)?

Thanks
Siegfried

Answer (score 2):

With EF5 you could use [EntityStoreSchemaGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.entitystoreschemagenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the model. In fact [it will still work](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1666) for EF6 models because EF5 models are compatible with EF6. The only difference would be that the provider manifest token generated for Sql Server 2012 will be "2008" when using EntityStoreSchemaGenerator while it will be "2012" whe using EF6 tooling (if you know that you are going against Sql Server 2012 you could replace it with 2012 manually once the model is generated). The code is generated using T4 templates. You could invoke the T4 template generation from PowerShell. It might not be straightforward since T4 is basically a VS thing but should be doable. To generate database from your code - one way of doing this would be to instantiate your context and call `ObjectContext.CreateDatabase` (or `ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript` if you need the script).

Comment: EntityStoreSchemaGenerator seems to no longer be compatible with EF 6.1.1. Is there a replacement for it anywhere?

Comment: In what sense it's not compatible with ef6.1.1? AFAIK the only thing that EntityStoreSchemaGenerator does not understand is manifest token for SqlServer 2012.However since you go from the other end (i.e. you use EntityStoreModelGenerator to create a model ant not to consume a model) it should work.

Comment: When I updated, I got compiler errors because namespaces like System.Data.EntityClient and System.Data.Metadata.Edm no longer existed. It seems these namespaces are shifted in 6.1.1 to live under System.Data.Entity.Core. However, I haven't found a EntityStoreSchemaGenerator under System.Data.Entity.Core, and the one in System.Data.Entity.Design returns types such as System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmSchemaError, which I can't seem to reference any longer. Compiler errors abound.

Comment: Now that I think about it, maybe the 6.1.1 version of System.Data.Entity.Design is distributed with the [6.1.1 version of the VS tooling](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762) and not with the EF Nuget package. Perhaps there's an updated version of EntityStoreSchemaGenerator that uses types compatible with System.Data.Entity.Core lurking in that package somewhere. I'll have to investigate that when I have time.

Comment: I was talking about the model and mot the code. For code you should use T4. You can find some details here http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/11/10/what-changed-in-the-ef-tooling-in-visual-studio-2013-and-visual-studio-2012-out-of-band/. Btw. There is no System.Data.Entity.Design for EF6.x. The latest one is for EF5 and is part of .NET Framework.

Comment: I am programmtically generating and consuming the schema at runtime. T4 is not an option. Are you saying it's impossible for me to upgrade to 6.1.1, because the ability to programmatically generate the schema from the database at runtime has been removed?